# How to get the child elements using Python webdriver

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

How to get the child elements class name using Python webdriver

I am able to go all td element using find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")

1. I want to access the child node
2. I want to get the attribute values of 'input class', 'type' ,
   'value','actiontypes', 'itemtype', 'aria-checked' -> ('checkbox',
   'checkbox', "undefined",'remove','song', 'false')

   Elm = WebElement(tds[2].parent,tds[2].id);

   ElmNew = Elm.find_element_by_class_name('checkbox');

Tried using find_element_by_class_name but got this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"checkbox"}' ; Stacktrace: Method FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ threw an error in file:///c:/users/<XXXX>/appdata/local/temp/tmpvsmd_c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this logic

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("td>input[class='checkbox']")
```

Actually `find_elements` will eturn a list of matching WebElement instances instead of a single matching instance.

So here you iterate that list to get individual WebElements. After getting the individual WebElements you can use `get_attribute(name)`

```
individualEle.get_attribute("value");
```